# How does Ruby's map method work in this case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dictionary

I got the mistake when I want to add doubled values to an array:

```
arr = [1,2,3]

def my_mistake(arr)
  result = Array.new
  arr.map { |element| result << element * 2 }
end
#=> [[2, 4, 6], [2, 4, 6], [2, 4, 6]]

def solution(arr)
  arr.map { |element| element * 2 }
end
#=> [2,4,6]
```

However, come back to my mistake and the definition of **map** method in Ruby.

> Invokes the given block once for each element of self. Creates a new array containing the values returned by the block.

I think **my_mistake** method has to return `[[2], [2, 4], [2, 4, 6]]` but it doesn't.

Everyone can explain this case for me ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The resulting array will contain three occurrences of the same reference to the same array, as `result` is the result of the expression `result << element * 2`. So the result of the `map` is (kind of) `[result, result, result]`. These all point to the *same* content, which is the content of `result` at the end of the process (`[2, 4, 6]`).

What you expected would be achieved if you clone the array at each point, so that every resulting element would point to a different array, and each addition would not affect the previously computed arrays:

```
arr.map { |element| (result << element * 2).clone }
=> [[2], [2, 4], [2, 4, 6]]
```

Comment: thanks a lot, **Patrice**, I can't vote up because of my reputation :(. Moreover, can you give me the link or source about your info ?: *The resulting array will contain three references to the same result*

Comment: @CuongVu from [`Array#<<`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C): *"This expression returns the array itself, …"*

Comment: @CuongVu Well, as Stefan pointed out, each evaluation of `result << element * 2` will come to `result`, whatever side effects this evaluation produces. And `result` is a reference that points to one and only one array in memory. When I say "...will contain three references to the same result", it is indeed misleading: it is more accurate to talk about *three occurrences of the same reference*.

Comment: @PatriceGahide and @Stefan: thank you very much. I think I understood the way ```map``` method works :)

Comment: More idiomatic, methinks: `arr.map { |element| result += [element * 2] }`.

Answer (score 0):

.map returns the last evaluated expression, so no need for the result << part there. Here's something that worked for me:

```
def my_mistake(arr)
  result = [] # '= []' is same like '= Array.new', look-up "literal constructors in Ruby"
  new_arr = [] # same like new_arr = Array.new
  until arr.empty?
    new_arr << arr.shift # we add each element of arr, one by one, starting from the beginning
    output << new_arr.map { |e| e * 2} # we calculate *2 for each element
  end
  return result
end
p my_mistake(arr) #=> [[2], [2, 4], [2, 4, 6]]
```

If you're nto sure how this works, try putting "p output" after the 6th line:

```
def my_mistake(arr)
  output = []
  new_arr = []
  until arr.empty?
    new_arr << arr.shift
    output << new_arr.map { |e| e * 2}
    p output
  end
  return output
end

my_mistake(arr)
```

The program will print:

```
[[2]]
[[2], [2, 4]]
[[2], [2, 4], [2, 4, 6]]
```

Comment: thanks **daremkd**, but I'd like to know how the ```map``` method really works. I don't want to return ```[[2], [2, 4], [2, 4, 6]]```. However, I think your solution is good for this case :).